# iOS - Universal link detection not working on physical devices (Working every time on simulator)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

Universal link working on simulator only every time when tap on it it will open application.

If i am directly run on device then it's not working it will just open safari not application. Same problem with .iPA file and TestFlight.

NOTES:
1. I am try to run on iOS 11.0 (iPhone 6s).
2. I have set and tried with debug and release both configurations.

Answer (score 0):

can You put a sample piece of code? I will be happy to test on my devices MAD give some clues.

I found a lot of sample code in stack overflow about it.